# ARC steeling my reference object (ODQuery)?

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, directoryservices

I'm slightly new to cocoa and have followed apples example here:
[Open Directory programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/Open_Directory/workingWithRecords/workingWithRecords.html)

In the example they grab the ODQuery object with a retain, this is not allowed anymore and I can't find any other way of telling the compiler to leave my reference alone. As I understand alloc doesn't do it either.

The reference seems to be lost when the ODQuery is passed to the NSRunLoop which in turn should pass it over to query:foundResults:error .

Here's the code (it should look for a group with the same name as my computer):

```
NSString *computer = [[NSHost currentHost] localizedName];
NSError *err;

ODQuery *aQuery = [[ODQuery alloc] initWithNode:adNode
                                 forRecordTypes:kODRecordTypeGroups
                                      attribute:kODAttributeTypeRecordName
                                      matchType:kODMatchBeginsWith
                                    queryValues:computer
                               returnAttributes:kODAttributeTypeStandardOnly
                                 maximumResults:0
                                          error:&err];

[aQuery setDelegate:self];
[aQuery scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

I assign adNode and session as private variables and assign them in the init method:

```
NSError *err;
NSString *nodeName = @"/Active Directory/GU/gu.gu.se";
theSession = [ODSession defaultSession];
adNode = [ODNode nodeWithSession:theSession name:nodeName error:&err];
NSLog(@"Error from initWorker: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
```

I've implemented the protocol ODQueryDelegate by overriding the method query:foundResults:error . When it gets called from the NSRunLoop the program crashes due to pointer errors.

```
- (void)query:(ODQuery *)inQuery foundResults:(NSArray *)inResults error:(NSError *)inError
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I would run with zombies enabled in the scheme in order to be **certain** which object is being released early.  You can then control the life cycle of that object by using `@property (strong)` instead of a local variable (assuming it turns out to be the one you suspect).

Comment: Setting it to strong did the trick! Sending some love your way :-) !